# Codeigniter site giving 404 page for every link

Tags: codeigniter

i have setup codeigniter site in my server with in a subfolder.

I changed the config url also in config.But when i click on any link in the site it is getting 404 page error.

here is the site link 192.185.167.23/~admirals/.

FYI my .htaccess file is empty.

What should i do for the links to be worked.

Comment: Does `192.185.167.23/~admirals/index.php` work ?

Comment: Yeah its working @YellowBird..

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in your `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And in your `config.php` file :

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

You also have to make sure that the `rewrite` module is activated in your apache configuration.

Comment: Still getting same 404 on links @Yello Bird